# Do any gunicorn worker types use multiple cores?

Tags: python, concurrency, gunicorn

Do any of the gunicorn worker types take advantage of multiple cores? Or is the only way to use multiple core to run multiple workers (processes)?

Comment: There isn't much multi-processing done in the Python world. Gunicorn, gevent and tornado all supports the standard multi worker paradigm. gevent and tornado do deal with event loops though.